# Functions in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new with Angular. I download JSON and then must handle it. I wrote something like a function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Objects.length; i++){

    $http.get($scope.Objects[i]["Commit"]).success(function(data) {
        Commit = data;
    })

        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Sorry we have some troubles... Try another time");});



        for (var j = 0; j < Commit.length; j++){
            //Metrics
            if (j = 0){
                for (var k = 0; k < Commit[j].length(); j++){
                    if (Commit[j][k] < 40){
                        $scope.Objects[i]["State"] = "Rejected"
                    }
                }
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            //Build
            if (j = 1){
                for (k = 0; k < Commit[j].length(); j++){
                    if (Commit[j][k] == false){
                        $scope.Objects[i]["State"] = "Rejected"
                    }
                }
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            //UnitTests

            if (j = 2){
                if (Commit[j][0] > 15){
                    $scope.Objects[i]["State"] = "Rejected"
                }
                for (k = 1; k < Commit[j].length(); j++){
                    if (Commit[j][k] < 40){
                        $scope.Objects[i]["State"] = "Rejected"
                    }
                }
            }
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            //FuncTests

            if (j = 3){
                if (Commit[j][0] > 2500){
                    $scope.Objects[i]["State"] = "Rejected"
                }
                for (k = 1; k < Commit[j].length(); j++){
                    if (Commit[j][k] < 40){
                        $scope.Objects[i]["State"] = "Rejected"
                    }
                }
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        }
    $scope.Objects[i]["Commit"] = Commit;


}`
```

but I can't handle it after `$http` because it isn't a `$scope` or even a function, I want use this piece of code how it is, like in pure JS. Is it possible.

Comment: I know that there is something like .service, but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Did you inject $http service in your controller ?

Comment: yes, i did, the $scope functions work well but this one can't understand $scope.Object

Comment: it's hard to guess then, can you provide complete example using say plnkr.co ?

Comment: any code sharing platform like - http://plnkr.co/ or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i can show you the full controller in jsfiddle without html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Bronzer/oxuh7h85/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77408/discussion-between---and-shershen).

Comment: You can't loop over `Commit` until it is returned from server. You need to loop over it in the success callback of $http

Comment: @shershen there's no guessing about processing asynchronous requests. The data must be returned before it can be processed

Comment: i understand it and fix it, but can i put that loop anywhere in cotroller without using scope

Comment: @charlietfl I know that; now trying to fix that sloppy fiddle

Comment: hah, thank you, cause i really know that it is more than sloppy

Comment: also need a closure for the `for` loops. `i` and `j` and `k` will all be at final values when requests return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First received data and only afterwards do operations with it. Otherwise it will be undefined. One of the ways it can be done like this, check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/oxuh7h85/22/

```
 $http.get('https://demo6732873.mockable.io/Users').success(function (data) {
            //MyData = data;
            $scope.Objects = data;
               console.log('data received - 3 ', data);
            $scope.runActionwithObjects();

        })
```

Comment: cheers! check if that works in your exact setup. if yes - accept the answer